# have shifted higher and lower

Tags: phrase-meaning

Is the polishing used in the phrase "have shifted higher and lower" an oxymoron? I don't quite understand it.

It perhaps means "(goals) have shifted higher and timelines have shifted lower." I am not sure.

> Joe Biden's coronavirus goals and timelines **have shifted higher and lower**
> WASHINGTON – When can most people get a COVID-19 vaccine? Do teachers need to be vaccinated before schools can reopen? When will life go back to normal?

> Those are some of the basic questions that the White House has sometimes struggled to answer as President Joe Biden tackles the biggest issue of his presidency: ending the pandemic and getting the economy and daily life back on track.

> Source: USAToday

Comment: *It perhaps means "(goals) have shited higher and timelines have shi[f]ted lower." ...* : I think you're right!

Comment: I think **both** goals **and** timelines are shifting which means they are unsettled, constantly changing time-wise, speed-wise, quantity-wise.

Comment: Another point of view: timelines are defined by goals, so if the timelines change, the goals must be adjusted accordingly...

Comment: @AndrewTobilko: You may well be right in terms of the real-world situation, but it seems beyond doubt to me that the author or the cited text intended it to be parsed as *coronavirus goals and timelines have shifted higher and lower **respectively*** (higher goals + lower/shorter timelines).

Comment: I think the original headline and the author's intentions are ambiguous.  It could equally well mean that both of them have gone up and down at different times. (Which makes it a not-very-well-written headline, IMO.)

Comment: @stangdon: Perhaps I missed something, but I can't see any mention in [the associated article](https://eu.usatoday.com/story/news/politics/2021/02/19/bidens-coronavirus-goals-and-timelines-have-shifted-higher-and-lower/6788140002/) of a single goal that Biden has shifted *downward*, or any evidence of him ever having shifted the timelines *upward*. And if the writers ***had*** intended both shifts in direction to apply to both nouns, it seems screamingly obvious to me the piece would have been intended to knock Biden's "policy vacillation". But it doesn't do anything remotely like that.

Comment: (The article is essentially "hagiography" - bigging up the pandemic *problems*, but equally bigging up Biden for being able and willing to tackle such problems.)

Comment: This is an example of vague writing which is actually poor writing, given that the goal of the headline is to be clear and accurate.